# partitioning blocks of elements from the indices of a numpy 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have the indices of a 2D array. I want to partition the indices such that the corresponding entries form blocks (block size is given as input `m` and `n`).

For example, if the indices are as given below

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 ]), array([0, 1, 7, 8, 0,1,7,8, 0,1,7,8, 0, 1, 7, 8]))
```

for the original matrix (from which the indices are generated)

```
array([[3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4],
       [4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 0, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4]])
```

and if the block size is (2,2), then the blocks should be

```
[[3, 4],
 [1, 3]]

[[2, 4] 
 [4, 0]]

[[2, 4]
 [0, 4]]

[[2, 1]           
 [2, 4]]
```

Any help to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? `A` is your matrix.

```
row_size = 2
col_size = 3

for i in range(A.shape[0] // row_size):
    for j in range(A.shape[1] // col_size):
        print(A[row_size*i:row_size*i + row_size, col_size*j:col_size*j + col_size])
```